# Meta tag cleanup

Tags: discussion, meta, faq-discussion

I cleaned up tags on a bunch of posts today, partitularly the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag. I removed a couple of posts that I haven't seen referenced in a long time and don't seem to be frequently encountered problems any more as well as a few that were specific to cleanup projects that are now historical (thank goodness!).

I added the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag to one new post, namely this one on [guidelines for subjective or practical questions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1376/30). The voting seems to indicate that there is a pretty concrete direction there.

Please understand my adding the `FAQ` tag to anything doesn't make it law, only that I'm trying to make the contents of that tag a meaningful representation of community consensus on key issues that keep coming up. **These items are still up for discussion and revision.** Feedback on what should or should not be tagged as `FAQ` can be given by answering this question. Only a moderator can actually use that tag, but we're here to listen to you and act on what the community wants to see happen.

Also for your convenience, I added a tags to differenciate between posts with guidelines for questions an answers. I hope this will make them easier to link from comments to help newcomers to the right information. For example:

- If somebody is having trouble with answers:
  you might want to point them to posts tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) + [answers](/questions/tagged/answers) with [this URL](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+answers).
- If somebody is having a problem with questions:
  you might want to point them to posts tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) + [questions](/questions/tagged/questions) with [this URL](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+questions).

While we're on the subject of comments, remember you can also point people to the main faq just by adding `[faq]` to your comment, but always [be](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/) [nice](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/week-2-of-the-summer-of-love-researching-comments/) and, particularly for new folks, verbose is usually better. Help them find these posts here on meta, but also explain specifically in regard to their post and why you think reading these guidelines would be helpful to them.

Comment: Dividing [meta-tag:questions] from [meta-tag:answers] seems an excellent choice.  They truly are different beasts.