# Does "faq" sometimes mean "recommended reading"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta, faq-discussion

Out of curiosity, I sorted the meta questions by votes just now, and saw that many of our great meta posts (ones that I would consider recommended reading for new users) are *not* tagged `faq`. Yet, some of the questions that are tagged `faq` are not exactly "frequently asked questions", but more like foundational material. These are the posts that "define" the site.

So, how are we using the `faq` tag on this meta? Should we change that? Should there be another tag like "recommended reading for the newbie"? I know for myself, I have recommended new users read meta questions tagged faq, but right now, I can see that they would have missed some of the most important posts I had in mind.

Comment: Related: [Meta tag cleanup](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1387/21576).  It does seem like it'd be worthwhile to do a bit more cleanup, to make sure that the most useful posts have that tag.

Comment: Caleb has often been the one to edit the faq tag, but he's been unavailable, right? I won't complain if you use your best judgement and just add/remove where necessary, @Nathaniel

Comment: He's around, just limited on time.  I've posted an answer to make sure we are more or less on the same page, and then in a few days I can make the adjustments.

Comment: @Nathaniel Thanks for getting this done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the most part, I think our FAQ questions are pretty good.  That said, I'm inclined to remove a couple and add a few.

I'd remove:

- [Pastoral Advice Questions](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/255/21576)

  - More of a policy discussion than a true FAQ. [This](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1588/21576) and [this](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6018/21576) provide clearer instructions and explanations.
- [What is “mainstream Christianity”?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/884/21576)

  - This could be edited into shape, but I think [this other FAQ question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1411/21576) more directly addresses the topic.

I'd add:

- [Brothers, we are not Christians‼](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/193/21576)

  - This is one we often point to once a new user challenges the site's format
- [We can't handle the truth](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3527/21576)

  - The point of this one is covered elsewhere, but this drives it home particularly well.
- [But can't I just say one thing?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1588/21576)

  - Often referenced in the context of pastoral advice questions

If you disagree, leave a comment below and we can adjust accordingly.

Also, a side note – a quick review of the various FAQ questions reveals that some cleanup wouldn't hurt.  [This one](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/725/21576) needs new screenshots, for one thing!  And a few have quite a bit of overlap, so perhaps they could be condensed or even combined.  But that's a subject for a different post...

Comment: I agree with this. Perhaps a few others warrant the tag as well. I'll add an answer for them.

Comment: Perhaps you overlooked this one due to undue modesty, but I'd suggest [this one](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6259/what-can-i-do-with-all-this-reputation) be added as well.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Nathaniel's suggestions, I also suggest adding the [faq](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) tag to the following:

1. [Christianity.SE vs. Survivor](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/132/3961)
2. One or both of the following:

   - [Christianity.SE 's experts are Christians, not scientists](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/308/3961)
   - [Are questions on a Creationist explanation for scientific observation on topic here?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3479/3961)
3. One or both of the following:

   - [The role of the non-believer on the site](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/64/3961)
   - [Are questions from atheists welcome here?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/493/3961)

With the questions in point 3, it might be better to make a new post: ask in good faith. Gotcha questions are obnoxious and can and should be politely approached instead. This would apply to rude atheists, proselytizing Muslims, and Christians trying to put down other Christians.

Comment: Good suggestion. One observation: 'Christianity.SE 's experts are Christians, not scientists' conflicts (at least in title) with 'Brothers, we are not Christians‼'

Comment: @bradimus Lol. Good catch. Is this irony? Anyway, cuz I can't tell through text if your aware, the Brothers post title is hyperbole, much like "We can't handle the truth".

Comment: Just the humor I found I the juxtaposition of the titles.

Comment: I do like your idea of coming up with a more general post for #3.