# Are questions about specific analytic theories and psycho-therapeutic approaches in pastoral counseling on topic?

Tags: discussion

If the question is asking about the intersection of theology and psychology, would it best be asked here or on [CS.SE](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/)? For instance, let's suppose I asked this question:

> Do any existing pastoral counseling programs take into effect how the
>   theological framework concerning the doctrine of free will affects the
>   counselor's therapeutic approach? For instance, an institution that
>   gravitates towards theological determinism (such as [Calvinism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calvinism) in
>   the Christian tradition) might be more likely to adopt an approach
>   based on radical behaviorism such as [CBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinical_behavior_analysis) (e.g. [ACT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptance_and_commitment_therapy), which
>   has an underlying worldview of [functional contextualism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_contextualism); or
>   functional analytic psychotherapy), while an institution that leans
>   towards theological indeterminism/libertarianism (such as
>   [Pelagianism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelagianism) or [Arminianism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arminianism) in the Christian tradition) might
>   feel more comfortable with standard [CBT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_behavioral_therapy) approaches.
>
> From my experience, most pastoral counseling programs seem to teach
>   some form of CBT without considering how the underlying worldview of
>   the therapeutic approach conflicts (or agrees) with the theological
>   ideologies of the institution and thus might create unintended
>   counter-transference. Has anyone dealt with this in scholarly
>   publications or studies? Do any institutions who teach pastoral
>   counseling directly address this issue?

**Question now asked:** [Has the impact of a practitioner's theological framework on pastoral counseling methodology been studied?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/15623)

Comment: FYI, Dan Allender and Jay Adams would be the people to talk about in such an answer.  Sadly, I'm not sure where it belongs though?

Comment: @AffableGeek no problem, I appreciate the referral. I'm not sure how I'd even go about trying to contact specific members on this site other than just "seeing them around," though.

Comment: Sorry - those guys are the ones I would call the leaders in the field.  You can google them.  They aren't users :)

Comment: @AffableGeek ahh gotcha. Thanks.

Comment: @AffableGeek I just saw that Adams is the nouthetic guy. I'll save my thoughts on that method for a rainy day (Thumper approach) :P

Comment: Hey - I gave you Allender too! But, yeah.

Answer (score 5):

After some thinking about this, I would argue that this question *should* be on topic, but would probably be considered off topic by many in the community.

There seems to be this idea that Christianity.SE is understood to be "Christian Doctrine".SE, and not "Christian Practice".  I have tried to get clarification around this on meta before [Broaden scope to include Church management?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/868/broaden-scope-to-include-church-management/869#869) but I'm not sure it ever got any traction.

Personally, I'd love to see this question, and would vote it up.

Comment: It should be included since the powers that be shut down those other proposals in favor of this one.

Answer (score 5):

In reading your sample question, I was already reaching for the +1 and the star to come back and check for answers. It's relevant to Christianity, demanding of expertise, carries a specific scope by which answers can be judged both on correctness and usefulness, and in all other ways seem to fit our existing criteria.

I fear since we haven't handled very many in this genre in the past it might get a bumpy reception. Also I can see it took a good deal of thought and background knowledge just to compose a good question of this sort. However these are problems that can be overcome.

I say lets have at it!

**Edit:** Here it is: [Has the impact of a practitioner's theological framework on pastoral counseling methodology been studied?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/15623/30)